# Making multiple if statements less verbose

Tags: python, filter, beautifulsoup, list-comprehension

I am scraping a webpage which doesn't use any helpful classes or ids in its html tags so I am having to scrap all links and look for patterns within links. Here is how a sample html may look like

```html
<span>Category</span><link href='example.com/link-about-a'>A</a>
```

On another page we might have a different category

```html
<span>Category</span><link href='example.com/link-about-b'>B</a>
```

Using beautifulsoup4, my current solution looks like this

```
def category(soup):
    for x in soup.find_all('a'):
        if 'link-about-a' in x['href']:
            return 'A'
        if 'link-about-b' in x['href']:
            return 'B'
```

and so on.. but this is very ugly.

I am wondering if there is a way to to make this less verbose.

Like using a dictionary

```
categories = {'A': 'link-about-a', 'B': 'link-about-b'}
```

and reducing it to a single expression.

Comment: How predictable are the patterns in the links? If substring match is the only way to find the patterns, Eric's solution is good. I personally might use a tuple of tuples rather than a dict for something that I'm just iterating over as key/value pairs, but that's a trivial difference. However, if you can reliably extract the pattern with something like a regexp, then having a dictionary that maps the patterns to the categories would be the best approach.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper The pattern is predictable and from predefined list of categories (A,B,C...) so you're right and I've found a regex implementation more useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need is another loop:

```
for x in soup.find_all('a'):
    for k, v in categories.iteritems():
        if v in x['href']:
            return k
```

Although if you want a single expression:

```
category = next((
    k for x in soup.find_all('a')
      for k, v in categories.iteritems()
      if v in x['href']
), None)
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be a little more flexible to use a list of regular expressions and categories:

```
categories = [[re.compile('link-about-a'), 'A'], 
              [re.compile('link-about-b'), 'B']]

def category(soup):
    for x in soup.findAll('a'):
        for expression, description in categories:
            if expression.search(x['href']):
                return description
    else:
        return None
```